# SQL - Data not been insert into SQL server instances

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, connection-string

I have two sql server

The first server is myservername\svr2.
The second server is myservername.

Both the server have the same table name = test123.
I want to use the first server with my c#.

I use

```
ConnectionString= "Data Source=myservername\\svr2,1433; Network Library=DBMSSOCN; Initial Catalog=mydb; Uid= user; Pwd=pswd;";
```

I found out that when i execute the insert query:

```
CommandText = "insert into test123 values ('name',123)";
```

It seems to be inserted in 'myservername' instead of 'myservername\svr2'.

Is there any wrong with my connection string? Or maybe the backslash gives problem?

Updated : sorry mistake on the slash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ConnectionString= ConnectionString= "Data Source=myservername\\svr2,namedinstancetcpport; Network Library=DBMSSOCN; Initial Catalog=mydb; Uid= user; Pwd=pswd;";
```

Named instance have their own TCP Dynamic Port. So instead of connecting to 1433, have to connect to the named instance TCP port.

Source: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc646023.aspx#BKMK_dynamic_ports

Comment: apparently the user don't want to use port number =_='

Answer (score 3):

Try reversing your slash as seen here.  [https://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlconnection/connection-to-a-sql-server-instance](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlconnection/connection-to-a-sql-server-instance/)/

Comment: sorry i have corrected my slash in the question. typo error

Answer (score 3):

I think the connection string should be

```
ConnectionString = "Data Source=myservername\\svr2,1433; …";
//                                          ^^
```

Comment: sorry i have corrected my slash in the question. typo error

Answer (score -2):

```
ConnectionString= "Data Source=myservername//svr2,1433; Network Library=DBMSSOCN; Initial Catalog=mydb; this.Uid= Uid;this.Pwd=pwd;";

CommandText = "insert into test123 values ("name",123)";
```

Comment: sorry i have corrected my slash in the question. typo error